# PayPal Mobile Express - Pay with credit card displayed instead of login screen

Tags: android, iphone, paypal

In our iPhone and Android app we have implemented mobile express checkout library. The problem is that instead of login window we have pay with credit card screen http://cl.ly/0U3b2e3g193L0w1E263v with a link to login at the bottom of the screen. Is there anything wrong and what can be done to change it to display the login window instead?

Answer (score 2):

In your SetExpressCheckout API call, set LANDINGPAGE to 'Login'. (LANDINGPAGE=Login)

Comment: We are still experiencing the problem with Billing screen instead of the Login screen.  
So we have the following code:  
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webscr">  
<input type=hidden name="SOLUTIONTYPE" value="Sole">  
<input type=hidden name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Login">  
<input type=hidden name="token" value="EC-61E33569KK1700215">  
<input type=hidden name="useraction" value="commit">  
<input type=hidden name="cmd" value="_express-checkout">  
<input type=submit title="Submit">  
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=".$payPalURL."'/>";

Comment: We form the following URL to paypal [link]https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Login&token=EC-61E33569KK1700215&useraction=commit , BUT for some reason, instead of the Login screen we see the Billing screen.

What is wrong?

Comment: `LANDINAGPAGE=Login` must be included in the SetExpressCheckout API call, not in the PayPal redirection URL.

Comment: Hi SpK; I haven't played with that myself. I would suggest you contact PayPal Developer Technical Services (www.paypal.com/dts/) they should be able to provide you with a 'Getting started' guide. Let me know if you run into any issues!

Comment: Hi Robert sir, they won't reply my question in [PaypalSupport](https://dts.custhelp.com/). I've asked in [X.com](https://www.x.com/) forum's also. Please see these questions - [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737052/android-mobile-express-checkout-library) and [X.com](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile-express-checkout/can-t-do-my-payment-process-mobile-express-checkout-library-android) I don't know what to do next. I've researched about this lot. No such solution i can't get. Please, help me.

Comment: They always respond - not sure what the original question was about since you deleted it now. Feel free to start a new question here and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

OK that was a problem in our code. We did have "billing" as landing page in other place.